# Unity URP pipeline: Why doesn't my custom shader render in the scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, urp

I create an empty project from Unity Hub's 3D URP template.

When I write a custom shader and use it in a scene, the object which uses this shader doesn't show in the scene and game window. When I turn off the SSAO in URP settings, the object can render in the game window, but still it doesn't show in the scene window.

My Unity version is 2021.3.7f1 [Apple silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon) version, and the URP template version is v2.0.6. My custom shader code is copied from URP's documentation. The link is:

*[URP unlit basic shader](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@16.0/manual/writing-shaders-urp-basic-unlit-structure.html)*

[image: object in scene]

[image: object in game]

I tried to edit URP rendering settings, but it didn't work. I didn't have any idea, so I asked this question.

This is the demo's link: https://github.com/tsx1453/ShaderProblemDemo

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, you need to add depthonlypass, which can be copied directly from lit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).